# awk unable to compare time with defined value

Tags: bash, awk

How to compare time using awk. I have been trying this using the below method but failing.

Column 4 from the below file should be printed whenever the "Lag" has crossed the value "24:00:00". But in my case only 2717:33:54 is getting printed. Where as all the lines should get printed.

```
bash-4.2$ cat test
Source  Destination     State           Lag             Status
Data1   Test:/data1     Complted        1239:30:37      Quiescing
Data2   Test:/data2     Complted        1239:30:13      Idle
Data3   Test:/data3     Complted        1208:37:21      Idle
Data4   Test:/data4     Complted        1208:36:46      Idle
Data5   Test:/data5     Complted        1239:29:41      Idle
Data6   Test:/data6     Complted        1239:29:26      Idle
Data7   Test:/data7     Complted        1239:28:52      Idle
Data8   Test:/data8     Complted        2717:33:54      Quiescing

threhold=24:00:00

cat test | awk -v threshold=$threshold '$4 > threshold'
Source  Destination     State           Lag             Status
Data8   Test:/data8     Complted        2717:33:54      Quiescing
```

Comment: @jaypal There's a typo in variable name in snippet. `threhold` on the assignment line. That changes the output for me to what he gets when I correct it. That being said I have no idea how awk is going to compare those fields. Badly I'm going to guess. Presumably string length and then positional character values. What it absolutely will **not** do is compute them as times.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ah, I just copy pasted.

Comment: `awk` is not particularly suited to working with date/time structures - it sees your fields as strings, not as the intervals you understand them as; as such, it's doing a lexicographic (i.e. dictionary order) comparison. You might want to try `python` or `perl` for better date/time handling functionality.

Comment: or use GNU awk which does have builtin date/time functions, but that's not necessary for this trivial case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, comparing 24:00:00 with 1239:30:37 is not going to do what you want, as the comparison is lexicographic (i.e. characters are compared one by one in alphabetical order). One option is to work exclusively in seconds and do numerical comparison instead. Here's how you could do that using a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -slane 'sub tt{($h,$m,$s)=split /:/,shift; return $h*3600+$m*60+$s}
             print if tt($F[3])>tt($t)' -- -t="$threshold" file
```

The subroutine `tt` splits the string it is passed on the ":". Given an input in the format "hours:minutes:seconds", it returns the total number of seconds. The `-a` enables autosplit mode, which means that the 4th column of the input on each line is stored in `$F[3]`. The value of the column in seconds is compared to the value of the argument passed at the end of the line. Lines where the lag is greater than `$t` are printed.

Testing it out:

```
$ perl -slane 'sub tt{($h,$m,$s)=split /:/,shift; return $h*3600+$m*60+$s} print if tt($F[3])>tt($t)' -- -t=24:00:00 file
Data1   Test:/data1     Complted        1239:30:37      Quiescing
Data2   Test:/data2     Complted        1239:30:13      Idle
Data3   Test:/data3     Complted        1208:37:21      Idle
Data4   Test:/data4     Complted        1208:36:46      Idle
Data5   Test:/data5     Complted        1239:29:41      Idle
Data6   Test:/data6     Complted        1239:29:26      Idle
Data7   Test:/data7     Complted        1239:28:52      Idle
Data8   Test:/data8     Complted        2717:33:54      Quiescing
```

As you tagged the question with awk, here's how you could do the same thing using awk instead:

```
awk 'function tt(t){split(t,a,/:/); return a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]}
     tt($4)>tt(t)' t="$threshold" file
```

The logic is the same as in the Perl example above.

Answer (score 5):

the string `2712:22:54` IS greater than the string `24:00:00` since the first char of each (`2`) is identical but then when you get to the 2nd char `7` is greater than `4` and all of the other strings are less than the string `24:00:00` since they all start with `1`. Maybe you wanted to use `0024:00:00` as the threshold? Alternatively convert all strings to integers (e.g. by `secs = hours * 60 * 60 + mins * 60`) to get a numeric comparison.